# Unity Изменения положения в иерархии

Tags: unity3d

У меня есть объект X. Который сейчас является Child другого объекта Y. Возможно ли программно перевести объект Х в Child зависимость другому объекту Z? Есть доступ ко всем объектам.

Comment: [Transform.parent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

Comment: @selya как же всё просто оказалось. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подхода два:

1. использовать специальный метод [Transform.SetParent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)
2. или напрямую задать родителя [Transform.parent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html)

В первом случае у вас есть возможность сразу определить стоит ли пересчитывать позицию, масштаб и поворот при смене родителя.